# C# get The most top, bottom, right and left point of a Rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I'm in this situation: I've a canvas that contains some rectangles that can also be rotated by an angle. I want to get the top, bottom, right and left end point of these rectangles, in order to draw a shape that can contains all of them.

Here's a figure:

[image]

I want to create a shape that match A,B,C,D points (A Polygon, not a rectangle).

How can I do this?

Comment: Since you know that each point will consist of X,Y coordinates, then if you have all of the points, you could determine which was the top (i.e. highest Y value), right-most (highest X value), etc.

Comment: Right - treat the four individual rectangles as one rectangle.

Comment: This is a general polygon merge problem. First, you need to insure that all polygons (the 4 rectangles in your case)  are clockwise. If not, invert coordinates order. Then, reduce the polygons count by merging polygons with common sides. *Clockwise test: Sum over the edges, (x2 − x1)(y2 + y1). If the result is positive the curve is clockwise, if it's negative the curve is counter-clockwise. (The result is twice the enclosed area, with a +/- convention*.).

Comment: The problem is that I really don't know how to get the most top, bottom, right and left points... From Canvas.getLeft/right etc methods I can get only the points of a non rotated rectangle...

Comment: How is the rectangle rotated?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through each of the rectangles and store the coordinates (X,Y) of each of their 4 points. Go through this list and pick the pairs that match your criteria i.e. greatest x, greatest y, smallest x, smallest y. Whichever pair of coordinates these 4 belong to are the edges of your polygon that contains your rectangles.